# Check if List<T> has any values without calling Count?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm curious if I'm overlooking something obvious: 
I often use `List<T>`, and I often need to check if it contains any values or not. I call `List<T>.Count()` to see if the count is greater than 0. This feels like an expensive operation to perform for just wanting to see if it contains *any* values.

Is there some overlooked method for checking this? A `IsEmpty()` kind of thing?

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
list.Any()
```

But this operation is just as cheap when you are actually dealing with a list.
If it's a collection that implements IEnumerable but not IList, using `Any` will be cheaper.

Answer (score 4):

> This feels like an expensive operation to perform for just wanting to
>   see if it contains any values.

Don't worry, the `.Count()` extension method will fallback to the `.Count` property if the underling type supports it.

Of course if at compile time you have an `IList<T>` then you'd better directly use the .Count property. But if you only have an `IEnumerable<T>` (whose concrete implementation happens to be a `List<T>`) you could use the `.Count()` extension method without any performance problems.